# what's the new equivalent of Rspec any_instance in Rspec 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

Normally in my Rails controller tests, I'll do `before { Website.any_instance.stub(:save).and_return(false) }` to test what happens when the record does not save. It looks like `any_instance` went away with Rspec 3.

I tried using `before { allow(Website).to receive(:save).and_return(false) }` for Rspec 3, but now I get this error:

> Website(id: integer, ...) does not implement: save

Is there a replacement for the very useful `any_instance` with Rspec 3?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this

```
allow_any_instance_of(Website).to receive(:save).and_return(false)
```

Eg: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#settings-mocks-or-stubs-on-any-instance-of-a-class